# Puppeteer - New window about:blank

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Am trying to interact with a new window that pops from a website when hittin a link. When this new window opens the link is: about:blank. When the link have something other than blank it works.
Does anybody knows an workaround?

Working (Link with something):

```
const newPagePromise = new Promise(x => browser.once('targetcreated', target => x(target.page())));
await page.click('#link-of-new-window');
const newPage = await newPagePromise;
```

Not Working (about:blank):

```
//not entering
browser.on('targetcreated', function(){
    console.log('New Tab Created');
});

const newPagePromise = new Promise(x => browser.once('targetcreated', target => x(target.page())));
await page.click('#link-of-new-window');            
const newPage = await newPagePromise; //hang in here forever
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you sure that the link opens a new window? Do you see this behaviour if you launch Puppeteer with `headless: false`?

Comment: Yes, am sure. I'm running headless false to see what is going on. I found a topic at puppeteer's github. Apparently it's a bug, but i'm trying to find an workaround as i can't manipulate the source code from the page am accessing. You can reproduce the error: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2810#issuecomment-401464252

Comment: Ah, I see. I hope the bug is fixed soon!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a bug. As mentioned before it's reported here: [Puppeteer's github.](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2810)

As a workaround i noticied that when a new window is created with some link, like this:

```
await page.evaluate(async () => await window.open("http://google.com","Schedule","menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1"));
```

the code follows to these functions:

```
_targetCreated
_targetInfoChanged
_targetInfoChanged
```

However, when a new window is created with auto:blank

```
await page.evaluate(async () => await window.open("","Schedule","menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1"));
```

this is the flow:

```
_targetCreated
_targetInfoChanged
```

So when i click a link that i know is auto:blank i search for a target that is not initialized 'target._isInitialized' and call the _targetInfoChanged again passing the targetInfo as parameter.
It's working for now. This is just an workaround until the bug is fixed.